# MFC Application: how to change LTR or RTL dynamically selecting language?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, right-to-left

I'm working to support LTR and RTL languages in our MFC Applications.
I have some problems with dialog controls, like editboxes, buttons; there is a global property to set the application work with "default" style layout as LTR or RTL or I have to check every control of every dialog on every dll and change the style of control as needed?

Thanks in advance!